# How to Select Specific Info From MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to a number from a specific table, row, and column but can't seem to get it right.

The table is `tblproducts`.  The column is `qty`.  And I need to select where `id` is `13`.

This is the code I'm using but it isn't returning anything:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","blank","blank","blank");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT qty FROM tblproducts");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['13'];
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

do it all in the query like so

`SELECT qty FROM tblproducts where id =13`

no loop needed

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT qty FROM tblproducts where id =13");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['qty'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sql syntax is a bit off, see my corrections. Your echo of the `row['13']` also looks suspicous. You can use `print_r()` to print arrays to find which key you need to use. It is probably `$row['qty']`.

```
 <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","blank","blank","blank");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT qty FROM tblproducts where id = 13");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
        print_r($row); // You can use print_r to have a look at your full array. The index '13' might not be what you where looking for.
      }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```